# Disable UIButton if UITextField and UITextView are empty in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitextview

My set up is simple:

1. I have a `UITextField` (input view is a pickerView)
2. I have a `UITextView`
3. I have a `UIButton`

I simply want the button to be disabled if **both** the textfield and textview are empty. And to enable it when they both contain something.

Nothing I try seems to work.

I create my button with this:

```
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 90, self.view.frame.width - 60, 50)
    button.center.x = self.view.frame.width / 2
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1).CGColor
    button.tintColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)
    button.setTitle("Send email", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Typo GeoSlab Regular Demo", size: 15)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "sendEmail:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

For the check on the text fields, I have tried this:

```
    if subjectTextField.text!.isEmpty || bodyTextView.text.isEmpty {

        button.userInteractionEnabled = false

    } else {

        button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

I have also tried this:

```
    if subjectTextField.text == "" || bodyTextView.text == "" {

        button.userInteractionEnabled = false

    } else {

        button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

I have added this code in the `viewDidLoad()` method, and also tried adding it in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method. Neither made any difference.

The button **always** remains enabled. Please help!
Thanks and let me know if you need any more info from me.

Comment: Try by checking length of text in textfield and textview... subjectTextField.text.length==0 || bodyTextView.text.length==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInteractionEnabled` ignores all user events, but does not 'enable/disable' the control. It's not what you need to set to do this.  You should be setting `button.enabled`. Enabled setting actually enables or disables the control.

```
  if subjectTextField.text!.isEmpty || bodyTextView.text.isEmpty {
       button.enabled = false
  }else {
       button.enabled = true
  }
```

And I would not do this in viewDidLoad as it will only run when the view initially loads - but rather the textviewDelegate method.

Comment: Can you suggest where would be best to put this code? Seeing as one is a UITextfield and the other is a UITextView...?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should be changing.

1. use `button.enabled` instead of `button.userInteractionEnabled`.  Although they both achieve the same end, the user will be able to see what's happening if you set the `enabled` status
2. You need to keep checking the status of `button` every time the text changes in your two fields.  You can use `textViewDidChange` for the text View provided you have added `UITextViewDelegate` to the class, and you can set up a `TextFieldDidChange` function of your own and link the `Editing Changed` event for the text field